# Magento 2 - How to add attribute in order shipping address block?

Tags: magento2

In magento 2 I try to add `company` attribute in admin > Sales > Order > edit > "shipping Address" block, between name and address :

[image]

Do you know how to make this change ?

**EDIT**

In `Store > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Address Templates`

In HTML there is "company" attribute :

```
{{if intitule_adresse}}{{var intitule_adresse}}<br/>{{/if}}
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}} {{if city}}{{var city}} {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}} {{/if}}<br />
{{var country}}<br />
{{depend telephone}}T: <a href="tel:{{var telephone}}">{{var telephone}}</a>{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br />F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br />VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

But It does not appear in shipping address.
When I remove `{{depend company}}{{/depend}}` and leave only `{{var company}}<br />` there is a blank line.

Comment: do you want that on specific location into shipping address?

Comment: Yes, between name and address (in 2nd position)

Answer (score 1):

**Go to**

```
Store > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Address Templates
```

**In HTML You Need To Add Your Attribute.**

```
{{depend attribute_code}}<br/>Attribute Label: {{var attribute_code}}
```

Comment: check you enter compny name in your address ??

Comment: The "company" attribute is already defined here, but does not appear: {{depend company}} {{var company}} <br /> {{/ depend}} (look at my update above)

Comment: Yes of course there is a company name

Comment: try create new order and fill the compny name and check because i also work on this so i am sure about this

Comment: I create new order, when I click on edit shipping address the company field is well filled but still does not appear...

Comment: Is it possible that there is an override of magento behavior in the code? But I don't know how to check this.

Comment: yes may be because i already check in fresh magento setup,,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102979/discussion-between-fabien-and-rk-rathod).